# How can I make my multiple join SQL query faster

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query that join 6 multiple tables. There are 2million rows in the table.

I wanted to first run the select to see how the data looks like before adding insert. For the purpose of brevity, I will refer to the query below as `my_query`.

Also note that I am using pgAdmin 4 on Postgresql.

my_query =

```
SELECT 
    td.a AS tba,
    td.b AS tdb,
    sd.a AS sda,
    sd.b AS sdb,
    sd.c AS sdc,
    sd.d AS sdd,
    sd.e AS sde,
    sd.f AS sdf,
    cd.a AS cda,
    cd.b AS cdb,
    cd.c AS cdc,
    cd.d AS cdd,
    se.a AS sea,
    se.b AS seb,
    se.c AS sec,
    se.d AS sed,
    ir.a AS ira,
    ir.b AS irb,
    ir.c AS irc,
    we.a AS wea,
    we.b AS web,
    we.c AS wec
FROM table1 td
LEFT JOIN table2 sd ON sd.timestamp = td.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 cd ON cd.timestamp = td.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 se ON se.timestamp = td.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 ir ON ir.timestamp = td.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table6 we ON we.timestamp = td.a
ORDER BY td.a ASC
```

Using query tool in pgAdmin, I run the query and limit the result to 1, I got the data I was expecting. But when I increase the limit to 10 rows it takes forever to load and there are 2million plus in the table.

Meanwhile when I use the COPY command in PSQL tool in pgAdmin like below limiting to 10 I got the result as in the sample result below.

```
COPY (my_query) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER \g /tmp/Crop_Facts_10.csv
```

Sample result

```
tba,tdb,sda,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde,sdf,cda,cdb,cdc,cdd,sea,seb,sec,sed,ira,irb,irc,wea,web,wec

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,12.26,39.50,4.88,24.49,3.36,7.53,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,354.42,,,,,,,,Snow,0.70,0.31

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,63.94,41.50,7.41,29.78,2.75,9.71,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,354.42,,,,,,,,NA,16.30,0.52

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,12.26,39.50,4.88,24.49,3.36,7.53,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,,,,,,,,,NA,16.30,0.52

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,12.26,39.50,4.88,24.49,3.36,7.53,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,,,,,,,,,Snow,0.70,0.31

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,63.94,41.50,7.41,29.78,2.75,9.71,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,,,,,,,,,Snow,0.70,0.31

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,63.94,41.50,7.41,29.78,2.75,9.71,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,354.42,,,,,,,,Snow,0.70,0.31

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,12.26,39.50,4.88,24.49,3.36,7.53,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,354.42,,,,,,,,NA,16.30,0.52

2022-09-12 14:37:00,2022-09-12,63.94,41.50,7.41,29.78,2.75,9.71,Corn,Vegetative,Whiteflies,,,,,,,,,NA,16.30,0.52
```

The column with ,,,,,,,,, are empty. But once I increased the limit to say 100 or more it takes like forever to load.

I am supposed to run an insert statement on this query on a temporary table I created to hold the result. But if the select statement can't load it means the insert statement will also fail.

Is there a better way to write the query to be faster?

Comment: use limit and offset if you no need to have an overview at once. Also make sure you have defined an index on timestamps.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour how do I do that?

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query, showing as much information as possible

Comment: Better than just `explain` use `explain (analyze, buffers) <Your select statement>`. Let it run to completion then update your question with resulting plan as text maintaining the indentation.  Include your table definitions (ddl) and all indexes on them; all as text - **no images**.

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the feedback. I tried to run the `explain (analyze, buffers)` with the query before but it was taking like forever to run in fact over 2 hours so I stopped it. Does it take that long?

Comment: It takes as long as it takes. Try removing all the JOINs (and associated columns), run the query and see how long it takes. Then add the JOINs back in one by one, running the query each time. This will help you identify where the performance issue(s) is/are - you'll probably need to add indexes to fix the problems you find. Also, if the number of records explodes when you join to a table, that probably tells you that you need to review your join conditions for that table

Comment: Can be!  It not only executes the query it captures the run time,the number of rows processed, the number of rows meeting criteria, the number not meeting criteria for each step and the process used (nested loop, hashed join, etc) and more. It is the only/best way of getting the complete picture. The goal is to optimize performance but that most often means taking steps backwards to see what needs to be done. Optimization is not *one-and-done*, but a process - sometimes a long iterative one. The process  @NickW suggests is a good one allowing you to identify bottle necks for further work.

Comment: Really, I was tired of waiting. I guess I have to try @NickW approach before falling back to using explain to see if I can identify the problem JOIN first. Thanks